# When did Obadiah receive prophecy?

Tags: nevua-prophecy, ovadya--book-of

We know *why* Obadiah merited prophecy ([Sanhedrin 39b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.39b.13?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi)).

But do we know *when* he receive prophecy? Was it before or after conversion? Are there any sources that indicate this?

Answer (score 1):

Considering he is not on the talmudic list of gentile prophets [Bava Batra 15b] , he must have become a prophet after his conversion.